# Modified Webforms project ro run MVC 4 but no mvc items in the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I modfied existing Webforms projects to run mvc 4 and I successfully did , however when I try to add new item such as mvc view or controller , I cant find them in the new items list , what should I modify to allow mvc items to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the Issue 
just add the bolded GUID to the ProjectTypeGuids tag 
**{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}**;{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}